# GNU make test output with leading spaces

Tags: makefile, whitespace, gnu-make

I want to output some text in the rule help of a makefile (GNU make).

```
help:
  $(info Help:)
  $(info )
  $(info make all   Build all targets)
  $(info make this  Build target this)
  $(info make long  Build target long that has)
  $(info            a very long description)
  $(info            that must be shown on)
  $(info            several lines)
  $(info make that  Build target that)
```

When calling `make help` I would expect:

```
Help:

make all   Build all targets
make this  Build target this
make long  Build target long that has
           a very long description
           that must be shown on
           several lines
make that  Build target that
```

But I get:

```
Help:

make all   Build all targets
make this  Build target this
make long  Build target long that has
a very long description
that must be shown on
several lines
make that  Build target that
```

How can the leading spaces be preserved?

**Edit:**

The solution has to work on Windows too.

**Solution:**

The trick is to add a variable containing a space. Then make does not strip the string.

```
SPACE := $(subst ,, )

help:
  $(info Help:)
  $(info )
  $(info make all   Build all targets)
  $(info make this  Build target this)
  $(info make long  Build target long that has)
  $(info $(SPACE)          a very long description)
  $(info $(SPACE)          that must be shown on)
  $(info $(SPACE)          several lines)
  $(info make that  Build target that)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use make's `info` function.  There is typically very little reason to use make functions like this inside a recipe: a recipe has the full power of the shell available and that's MUCH more powerful than GNU make function capabilities.  Use the shell's `echo` function instead:

```
help:
        echo "Help:"
        echo
        echo "make all   Build all targets"
        echo "make this  Build target this"
        echo "make long  Build target long that has"
        echo "           a very long description"
        echo "           that must be shown on"
        echo "           several lines"
        echo "make that  Build target that"
```

**ETA**

If you really want to use `$(info ...)` for portability then you'll have to play a trick:

```
E :=

help:
        $(info $E        indented text)
```

This makes an empty variable `$E`, then you can use that and it will mark the end of the whitespace separating the function name from its arguments.

Comment: On Windows the shell is typically not much more powerful. But it is VERY different to all other shells. On Windows your solution does not work or at least has other problems (one can not print an empty line).

Comment: @Teddy Would `echo ""` print an empty line on Windows?

Comment: You didn't say anything about windows in your original question.  It's generally very very very difficult to write a makefile that runs across multiple systems.  @Jens no on Windows (assuming your make invokes cmd.exe not sh.exe) `echo ""` will print `""`.  The command shell in Windows doesn't do anywhere near the same sort of command line handling as a POSIX shell.

Comment: On Windows you can use `echo.` and it will print a blank line, but of course that won't print a blank line on POSIX.

Comment: Actually, it's simpler than what I suggested.  You don't need to make a variable with a space in it.  You just need an empty variable: something to get make to stop eating whitespace after the function name and before the first argument.